# Cannot receive php echo when using AJAX for loading screen

Tags: php, html, ajax, echo

so Im trying to do a loading screen for a webpage while a php-file gets executed because the php-file fetches data from a MYSQL Server and that can take a while sometimes.

So my php-File is named "connect.php" and echos html code and does NOT need any parameters when called. Here is a simple overview so you get a Idea what it does. The whole file works when I dont use AJAX and just include it normally.

```
<?php

if (!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') die('Invalid request');

//MYSQL-Connection

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo //// Some HTML Code            
        }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

And there is my index.php where I use AJAX to call the php-file:

```
<section id="intro" class="wrapper style1">             
            <style>#loading { display:none; }</style>
            <div id="loading">Test</div>
            <div class="container">
                <span>
                    <script>
                        $( '#loading' ).show();                     
                        $.ajax( {
                            url: 'connect.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'html',
                            success: function () {
                                $( '.container' ).html();                                   
                                $( '#loading' ).hide();
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert( "Something went wrong!" );
                            }
                        } );
                    </script>
                </span>
            </div>
</section>
```

So the console doesnt put out any errors and for a short time (when the php loads the word "Test" gets printed on the screen but then nothing happens and I dont know why. And like I said when I include the php-file like this `<?php include_once('getcelebration.php'); ?>` everything works just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We see a lot of questions from new contributors, and often they are lacking a lot of information. Yours doesn't. An execellent question! Your problem is that you don't process the data received through `success`. See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax Note the `data` argument in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `data` argument in `success` function, as these are the call back functions they return the data which passes from the `request_url` which is `connect.php` in your AJAX request.

Try this:

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $( '.container' ).html(data);
    $( '#loading' ).hide();
}
```

Comment: How about actually putting the HTML in the container?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, missed that.

Comment: No problem. Sigmar should now be able to work with this.